# Copy First x rows of visible data using SpecialCells add to new sheet AND delete each copied row from original table

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I need to copy the first X rows of visible data in the image below into a new sheet AND delete every row that has been copied (rather than just clearing the data).

For example, in the image below, let's say I just need the first 7 visible rows of data after I filter column 7. I need these first 7 visible rows pasted in the Fulfillment sheet AND I need the rows to be entirely deleted (not cleared) from the table as I can't have blank rows left over. Instead of 7, this could easily be a number in the hundreds, needing to be repeated dozens of times for each order that needs fulfilling.

Is there any solution other than looping through the entire table until you reach the n'th visible row to do this? This code will need to fulfill hundreds of orders with thousands of phones so it can't be slow.

It would be perfect if there were code that just said offset to the 22nd visible row or something.

I have no code because this is purely conceptual at this point.

[image: Inventory to be copied - example]

---

**Tried this:**

```
msgbox Range("A362").Offset(6,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
```

That code should return 432, but it's returning 1 instead.

Comment: You can use `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` with `Offset` to achieve that. More about [Special Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells)

Comment: I have tried this - can you give me  a specific line of code that would offset from cell A362 to A432 using the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) and Offset code?

Comment: msgbox Range("A362").Offset(6,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row

That code should return 432, but it's returning 1 instead...

Comment: `Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.address`

Comment: Hi Mikku - it seems like all the comments are gone - did you see my last comment about adjacent visible rows being treated as a single contiguous area - so the code you wrote only works in your example because each of your visible rows is followed by a hidden row instead of having multiple visible rows right next to each other like I have in my example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707693/select-top-n-rows-in-table-after-filter-with-vba

Comment: https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2014/03/11/top-ten-values-in-filtered-rows/

Answer (score 0):

As, really, there is no code to work with... what you are asking for should be like:

```
LastRow = Sheets(2).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
MsgBox LastRow
For i = 1 To 7
    Sheets(2).Range("A1").Offset(LastRow + i - 1, 0). _
         SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Value = _
         Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i, 0). _
         SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Value
Next
For i = 8 To 2 Step -1
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i + 1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow. _
                                                               ClearContents
Next
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

That one is considering that there are just 2 sheets, that the data have the same setup that you send in your screen capture.

This code will copy the first 7 rows on sheet(1), they will be copied on Sheet 2 and the rows copied will be deleted.

Hope it helps

Comment: why do people keep suggesting Offset combined with SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) in filtered tables? It is not working for me - if the table is unfiltered, it works. If it is filtered, the following code selects the entire data body range of the table.

Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(i+1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Select

Comment: It seems that there is a problem when you ask for deleting the row. I just changed to ClearContents and then Delete. I checked with filters and it works.